# Create next app causes error - casing - There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js, git-bash

Steps I took:

**1. Have vscode open with terminal set to gitbash and pointing to empty directory c:\apps**
**2. Open cmder. (a colour coded terminal)**
**3. From Cmder: npx create-next-app@latest projectname --typescript**

**4. Select default options**
Need to install the following packages:
create-next-app
Ok to proceed? (y) y
√ Would you like to use ESLint with this project? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use `src/` directory with this project? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use experimental `app/` directory with this project? ... No / Yes
√ What import alias would you like configured? ... @/*

**5. cd projectname**
**6. npm run dev**

**Error**

> _Import trace for requested module:
> ./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/is-bot.js
> ./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js
> ./node_modules/next/dist/client/router.js
> ./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/on-demand-entries-client.js
> ./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/is-dynamic.js
> There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
> This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
> Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:

- c:\apps\projectname\node_modules\next\dist\compiled@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!c:\apps\projectname\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[2].use[1]!C:\apps\projectname\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\is-dynamic.js
  Used by 4 module(s), i. e._